# Certificate Pinning on Android / iOS in-App Browser

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, certificate-pinning

My company follows certificate pinning for mobile. We're starting to add login via an in-app browser in our mobile apps (similar to google, facebook, and other enterprise companies). I spoke to the web team implementing this feature, and they'd never heard for certificate pinning, which is a common practice on mobile.

I'm curious if chrome / safari automatically certificate pin, or if it's something you have to do manually in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious if chrome / safari automatically certificate pin, or if it's something you have to do manually in the browser.

Chrome was supporting [HPKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) but its has been [removed](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5903385005916160) in Chrome 72 release for both desktop and Android versions.

You can see a complete list of browser supporting it [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=hpkp), that now looks like this:

[image]

But ironically this site says that is removed for the desktop, but not for Android, and it seems that was never supported in iOS Safari.

> and they'd never heard for certificate pinning, which is a common practice on mobile.

I would like to alert you for the fact that certificate pinning can be bypassed, therefore you cannot use it as the only security measure. You can read more in an article I wrote, [Bypassing Certificate Pinning](https://blog.approov.io/bypassing-certificate-pinning) to see how certificate pinning can be bypassed in a mobile app.

> In this article you will learn how to repackage a mobile app in order to make it trust custom ssl certificates. This will allow us to bypass certificate pinning.

Comment: I disagree with your points of bypassing certificate pinning. Once you've ceded that an attacker can modify the installed application, anything and everything can be bypassed, including code. You could also bypass it by removing the certificate pinning configuration in the dex byte code, or intercepting the traffic after it's decrypted on the device and sending it to another server. If an attacker can gain physical access to the device, and modify an installed application, all bets are off.

Comment: @spierce7 I state in my article that certificate pinning bypassing illustrate there is in the context of an attacker using a device it controls, and I have illustrated the easiest way of doing it, but other more complex ways exits, like removing the dex byte code, as you mentioned, or by using an instrumentation framework, like Frida or xPosed during runtime, like in this [video](https://youtu.be/yJRlMmJjrhY). Common uses for an attacker to bypass pinning in app on its own device is to learn how the communication happens between the app and the API, and then mount an attack against the API.

Comment: @spierce7  And yes in a device an attacker controls, he can change code behavior and even grab encrypted data by hooking on the correct calls, using once more Frida or xPosed. Now regarding modifying and bypassing pinning in a device he cannot control is another history, but not an impossible one, but requires a chain of exploits/actions, and that the user installs some compromised app by social engineering him to do so.